# AWS SSL Certificate without Load-Balancer?

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-cloudfront

I have a standard Elastic Beanstalk app set up and running great over HTTP. Following the [AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html) I requested an SSL Certificate and configured it with CloudFront.

Instead of a load-balancer I am adding an ingress rule to the AWSEBSecurityGroup security group that opens port 443 to all traffic for a single instance environment. [Detailed here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance.html).

Using this snippet;

```
Resources:
sslSecurityGroupIngress: 
Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
Properties:
  GroupId: {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["AWSEBSecurityGroup", "GroupId"]}
  IpProtocol: tcp
  ToPort: 443
  FromPort: 443
  CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

and uploading it to .ebextensions/https-instance-securitygroup.config on the server. However the SSL certificate is still not working. I am unsure why, have I missed something?

Thanks.

Comment: Check in CloudFront console to see if the SSL certificate has been assigned to the distribution.

Comment: @Tim Yes it has been assigned to the distribution, just double checked just now.

Comment: I would try setting it up manually in the console, then having CloudFormation generate the template to create it. Compare that with what you did and you should have your answer.

Comment: If you haven't installed an SSL certificate on the *instance itself*, CloudFront will not be making a back-side connection to the instance using SSL.  Please be more specific than saying it is "not working."